# Xcode 10 "Could not build module Darwin / Foundation / CoreFoundation" etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fastlane, xcode10

After switching to Xcode 10 (**Have to use legacy build system for now**), I started getting errors shown below. Locally I was able to fix them by pretty much cleaning everything I can i.e. `Derived Data / Build etc...`

Debug and Release runs in Xcode run fine for me, however I've been struggling to solve this issue in our CI (bitrise).

We use Fastlane and our lane has steps to clear derived data and perform clean build.

```
clear_derived_data
build_ios_app(
  workspace: "application.xcworkspace",
  scheme: "application",
  clean: true
)
```

Yet these errors keep happening (these are few examples, there are around 30 errors like this following one another and pointing to same packages like Darwin etc..):

```
❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Headers/CoreFoundation.h:16:10: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <sys/types.h>
         ^~~~~~~~

❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/usr/include/dispatch/dispatch.h:25:10: could not build module 'Darwin'
#include <Availability.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^

❌  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/Foundation.h:6:10: could not build module 'CoreFoundation'
#include <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^

❌  /Users/vagrant/git/packages/skimitar-app/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/functions/RNFirebaseFunctions.h:3:9: could not build module 'Foundation'
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
 ~~~~~~~~^
```

**EDIT:** Does legazy build setting persist i.e. if set in our Xcode and committed to git, will ci also use legacy build system?

Comment: Have you check your build system? from File > Project/Workspace Settings

Comment: @guru yeh, its set to `Legacy Build System` under Shared Workspace Settings and `Use Shared Setting` under Per-User Workspace Setting, that is correct. I wonder now if this is only set in my local XCode and not carried over as a setting to CI version of XCode somehow?

Comment: Seems like it should there is `BuildSystemType -> Original` key in my .xcsettings file

Comment: Have you fixed it?

Comment: @guru no, all of this was set up already prior to this question.

Comment: Any luck? It is a strange issue, I am also seeing the same thing.

Comment: @Adam nothing yet for me. Works fine locally, not on CI however. I suspect CI is having issue using legacy build mode, perhaps this is related to XCode cli tools, not sure

Comment: yes, legacy build setting persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you are using Bitrise, go to 'Xcode Archive & Export for iOS' step.
2. Scroll down and expand the 'Debug' section.  Scroll down to 'Do a clean Xcode build before the archive?' and change this to 'yes'.
3. Save your settings start a new build, do not rebuild as it will use the old settings.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve this issue by setting the build system to Legacy.

Open the `PROJECT_NAME.workspace file`

Then in the top menu select `File > Workspace Settings`

Then change `Build System` to `Legacy Build System`